# Apple ID Hangs without error virtualbox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, apple-id

Hello intelligent people,

I am trying to use Mac OSX El Capitan on virtual box and so far it has been working perfectly, save for one important factor. Whenever I try to use anything involving an Apple ID, it just hangs there after I hit sign in. The internet is perfect, I tried the browser, and I tried setting a random serial number other than 0.

Can anyone help? I really need to be able to use the Apple ID system.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use the underlying Mac's actual serial number?

Comment: Same error, i also dont want to use this as a solution because it may conflict with servers or something, you know, just in case